# AAD client-credentials flow request scope for web api

Tags: c#, azure-ad-msal, scopes, clientcredential

I got a console app that needs to support two flows, authenticating against AAD to talk to a web api:

- for regular usage by humans, it needs to support interactive login
- for usage by a CI/CD pipeline it needs to support client-credentials.

The interactive flow works perfectly, but the client-credentials flow is giving me problems with the requested scope.

I'm using the latest `Microsoft.Identity*` nuget packages.

When I construct the scope for the webapi like I do for the interactive flow, I get an error message telling me that for client-credentials flows I need to append `./default`. Okay, fair enough, I also found [documentation](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-credential-flows#scopes-to-request) for this, so I append `./default`. But when I do that, I get another error message telling me

> The resource principal named api:///access_as_user was not found in the tenant named .

There are two problems with this error message:

- the resource principal quoted definitely exists - also, I couldn't login interactively if it didn't, but as mentioned, interactive login works just fine
- it says `api://<webApiAppId>/access_as_user`, not `api://<webApiAppId>/access_as_user/.default`, despite my appending that

My next though was: well, maybe the problem is that the app registration used for the client-credentials flow doesn't have permissions on the web-api. But it does.

So now I've run out of ideas. Hopefully, someone here can help.

To make everything a bit clearer, let me list the app regs involved:

A. Web Api

- Was setup via the VS Wizard/dotnet-msidentity tool
- has a few App Roles defined
- exposes a single API `api://<itsownAppId>/access_as_user`

B. Interactive Login

- manually created
- redirect URI for localhost
- API Permissions: added `WebApi | access_as_user` as delegated

C. Non-interactive login/Service Principal

- setup manually
- is used also for other things by the CI/CD pipeline
- has a ClientSecret defined
- API Permissions: added `WebApi | access_as_user` with 2 of the app roles defined for A
- has other API Permissions that have nothing to do with this here (for Graph)
- granted admin consent for all permissions

The code I use to authenticate is (for the confidential flow):

```cs
ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(_configuration.ApplicationId)
            .WithTenantId(_configuration.Directory)
            .WithLogging(Log, LogLevel.Error)
            .WithClientSecret(_configuration.ClientSecret)
            .Build()
            .AcquireTokenForClient(_configuration.Scopes)
            .ExecuteAsync();
```

where the values of `_configuration` are:

- `ApplicationId`: the appId from app registration C
- `Directory`: the name of my AAD tenant
- `ClientSecret`: the secret from app registration C
- `Scopes`: array of `openid`, `profile` and `api://<appIdOfWebApiFromC>/access_as_user/.default`

Answer (score 1):

So, it turns out that the documentation for appending `./default` is not quite clear enough:.You are not meant to append it to the scope, just to the "resource id". And with resource id they mean the "api://" parts **without** the name of the permission.

So where you normally request `api://<webApiAppId>/access_as_user`, for the client-credentials flow you have to request `api://<webApiAppId>/.default`